# Measuring the balance of a rowing boat

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

Basically, I'm an amateur rower with mechanical engineering experience, however I am lacking in electronic knowledge. I need to find a way of measuring the pitch of the boat whilst I'm rowing, the reason for this is that I'm informed the balance of the boat affects the speed.

I was thinking of using an accelerometer.

Just wondering if there are any other viable ways of doing this, as I want to be sure this is the best way of doing so.

Comment: Are you interested in the pitch of the boat during your power stroke, glide stroke, or both?  What pitch angle resolution requirements do you have?

Comment: The set also affects speed (roll). Usually you can tell the set based on which side the boat leans, the gunnels should be paralell to the water level. For your purpose, I reccomend a 9˚ of freedom sensor

Answer (score 4):

Yes, an accelerometer (or two, or three) is what you need to implement an inclinometer.  In a quick search I found a three axis accelerometer [breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9156) suitable for interfacing with the Arduino (since you used the "Arduino" tag on your question).  To report the inclination angle, you would have to apply the appropriate trigonometric functions to calculate inclination from the reported acceleration values.  Some three-axis accelerometers have built in inclinometer functionality in that they are capable of doing the trig calculations internally.

I’m not sure what effect that the acceleration from rowing might have on the results… perhaps a little analysis would be needed there.

Or, from the purely mechanical side, would a bubble level of some type or perhaps a pendulum like hanging weight be appropriate?

Disclosure: My employer manufactures the accelerometer on the breakout board linked above.

Comment: thanks guys, this has been a massive help to me, I will look into using the arduino shield as I need to collect the data for research post each session

Answer (score 0):

There are inclinometer apps on smart phones that might have the user interface you need. iPhone App supports calibration with a resolution of 0.1deg

more on [rowing tricks](http://www.sykesna.com/Resource%20Centre/rocker.htm)